# Swift Push Notifications send if api change

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

How to send notification when api changes its data? I am getting data from url. When the data at this address changes, the user must receive it. I tried to use *"UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)"* but it sends the notification without change.

```
func apiNotification(urlString:String){
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            parse(jsonData: data)
        }
    }
}

private func notificationSend(id:String, title: String, introtext: String){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.subtitle = title
    content.body = introtext
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 30, repeats: false)
    let uid = UUID.init().uuidString
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else{
            print("Notification Register Success")
            print("===================================")
        }
    }
}
private func parse(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiData.self, from: jsonData)

        notificationSend(id:decodedData.id, title: decodedData.title, introtext: decodedData.introtext)
     } catch {
        print("decode error")
    }
}
```

API JSON:

```
{
  "id": "176",
  "title": "Notification title 1",
  "introtext": "Notification introtext 1",
}
```

Changed JSON API:

```
{
  "id": "177",
  "title": "Notification title 2",
  "introtext": "Notification introtext 2",
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your API must send an event when the data is changing. You must use the framework that Apple is providing; you need to enable this in the app settings, under capabilities, then push notifications. And your API needs to use a key registered in the Apple Developer Platform.

More details in this tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I have push notifications setup and tested via apple console. but how am I listening to the api? I just do a get request to get the weather at launch or if the user changes location, is there another option to listen to the api all the time?